# how to pick single current page using echo with li?

Tags: php

i would like to retrieve single current page instant off full menu with currents
menu code :

```
 <?php
$sql = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM pages WHERE isRoot='1' ORDER BY pageID");
        while ($row = mysql_fetch_object($sql))
        {
            echo "<li class=\"current\"><a href=\"".DIR."?p=$row->pageID\">$row->pageTitle</a></li>"; 
        }
    ?>
```

preview code :

```
?php    
    //if no page clicked on load home page default to it of 1
    if(!isset($_GET['p'])){
        $q = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM pages WHERE pageID='1'");
    } else { //load requested page based on the id
        $id = $_GET['p']; //get the requested id
        $id = mysql_real_escape_string($id); //make it safe for database use
        $q = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM pages WHERE pageID='$id'");
    }

    //get page data from database and create an object
    $r = mysql_fetch_object($q);

    //print the pages content
    echo "<h1>$r->pageTitle</h2>";
    echo $r->pageCont;
    ?>
```

but it gives me li pages marked with current

Comment: What do you expect it to output?

Comment: want to output current li with single page not the whole page

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I understood what you meant... I would try something like this:

```
<?php
$sql = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM pages WHERE isRoot='1' ORDER BY pageID");
    while ($row = mysql_fetch_object($sql))
    {
       $active = '';
       if($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'] == DIR . '?p=' . $row->pageID)
           $active = 'class="current"';
       echo "<li " . $active . "><a href=\"".DIR."?p=$row->pageID\">$row->pageTitle</a></li>"; 
    }
?>
```

This way, you will only add the 'class="current"' if the user is actually on this page.

Hope this helps!